# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este error en mi codigo que dejo anexado,lo que quiero es mostrar las iteraciones que se tienen en una lista pero me salta ese error alguien sabe que ocurre,cualquier sugerencia agradezco.

**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
34
35     if i == 1:
---> 36              print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr)))
37     elif i > 1:
38              print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.10f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr),Er))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format****

Este es el codigo

```
from numpy import exp 

Ri = 15
Rr = 31/2
Rs = 16
i = 0
Er = 0
Rra = 0

def F(n):
    return 745*1-exp(-x/10)-49*(x)

    #Funcion para calcular el error relativo
def error (Rra,Rrn):
    Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
    return Erel

print ('{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format('# iter','Ri','Rs','Rr','F(Ri)','Erel(%)'))
      
while (i < 10):
    Er = error(Rra,Rr)
    Rra = Rr #Rra sera el Rr anterior para determinar el error relativo
    if F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es',Rr)

    Rr = (Ri + Rs) / 2
    i = i + 1

        #Condicional para el primer error relativo

    if i == 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr)))
    elif i > 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.10f}'.format(i-1,Ri,Rs,Rr,F(Rr),Er))
```

Comment: El error indica que estás pasando a `str.format()` un parámetro que es un array numpy, pero que en la cadena de formato estás poniendo un especificador de formato que no es válido para un array. Posiblemente se trate de alguno de los `{:^15.6f}`, ya que estos especifican formato para **un** dato de tipo flotante, pero lo que estás pasando ahi en cambio es un array numpy. Revisa qué variables pasas en las líneas del print y qué es lo que realmente quieres mostrar en él, si un array o un numero.